# Authentication for REST-Service with spring-security and Basic Auth

Tags: spring-security, basic-authentication

I am trying to implement Basic Authentication for my REST-Service with spring-security with the following requirements:

- Authorization is done by other parts of the app (so no roles in the filter chain)
- i want to configure everything with plain beans without any autoconfiguration

What confuses me is the fact that the BasicAuthenticationFilter does'nt without an "Authorization"-Header, so effictively allowing access for all requests without that header.
I excepted such requests to throw an Exception and than redirecting to an/the *authenticationEntryPoint* .

My code is as follows:

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/rest/**" filters="basicAuthenticationFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

```
<bean id="basicAuthenticationFilter" class="authentication.MyBasicAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="myAuthenticationManager" />
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint" />
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="myRealm" />
</bean>
```

My assumption is, that i might need an *filterSecurityInterceptor* and following that one also an *accessDecisionManager*. I would not like to use those as it seems to me they care about Authorization (in contrast to Authentication) and i don't have any roles at this point of my application.

I just want to check for a correct username/password combination 
and react accordingly(401 or 403).

I guess i am missing something very basic, so any hints or help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no authorization (from Spring Security's perspective) then any requests are allowed and thus there is no need for authentication. So yes, you need a `FilterSecurityInterceptor`, even if it only makes a decision based on whether the user is authenticated or not.

You also need a `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` at the start of the filter chain since, even if your application is stateless, the security context needs to be cleared at the end of each request.

You might find [this article](http://spring.io/blog/2010/03/06/behind-the-spring-security-namespace/) useful as it discusses plain bean configuration in more detail.

Comment: When using 'FilterSecurityInterceptor' i would have to define an 'AccessDecisionManager'. As i only want to authenticate (i.e. proof somebody has a valid pair of credentials) my assumption would be i can achieve this by providing a 'AccessDecisionManager' und providing it with an 'SecurityMetadataSource' as follows: '<property name="securityMetadataSource">
            <security:filter-security-metadata-source use-expressions="true">
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
                    access="isAuthenticated()" />
            </security:filter-security-metadata-source>'